Access elements in list<vector<int>> without using temporary space
I had a query on how to access the elements in a list<vector<int>>, I can access the elements by assigning the values of the iterator into a temp vector. For example,
list<vector<int>> a={{3,10,1},{5,10,0}};

auto it=a.begin();
vector<int> temp=*it; // This is acceptable
int t1 = *it[0]; // This is not acceptable

But I want to access the elements in the second way i.e, without assigning values to any temp space. Is it possible?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence: [] has a higher precedence than *, but you want to first apply * to it and then [] on its result. So: (*it)[0].

What does this question even mean?

This is not acceptable is this a compiler message? Throw the compiler away. If not, learn How do I ask a good question?

@user17732522 thanks for the reply this resolved my issue.

@3CxEZiVlQ I'll look into it.

Your "acceptable" line creates a copy. So this:
{
  auto it=a.begin();
  std::vector<int> temp=*it;
  temp.push_back(0);
}

will have no effect. Instead you can either hold a const or non-const reference:
{
  auto it=a.begin();
  auto const& immutable = *it;
  return immutable.size();
}

or
{
  auto it=a.begin();
  auto& ref = *it;
  ref.push_back(0);
  return ref[0];
}

Of course, you don't have to hold a reference in the first place.
auto it = a.begin();
(*it).push_back(0);
// or
it->push_back(1);
return (*it)[0];


Thanks I needed the () brackets before accessing the elements thanks for ans.
